# Performing PostgreSQL LEFT OUTER JOINS and CASEs in Django

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

So I have a fairly involved sql query here.

```
SELECT links_link.id, links_link.created, links_link.url, links_link.title, links_category.title, SUM(links_vote.karma_delta) AS karma, SUM(CASE WHEN links_vote.user_id = 1 THEN links_vote.karma_delta ELSE 0 END) AS user_vote
FROM links_link
LEFT OUTER JOIN auth_user ON (links_link.user_id = auth_user.id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN links_category ON (links_link.category_id = links_category.id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN links_vote ON (links_vote.link_id = links_link.id)
WHERE (links_link.id = links_vote.link_id)
GROUP BY links_link.id, links_link.created, links_link.url, links_link.title, links_category.title
ORDER BY links_link.created DESC
LIMIT 20
```

All my relations are good (I think) and this query works perfectly when I run it in my navicat for postgresql but turning it into something Django can use has been quite the challenge.  I am using the pre-alpha 1.2 development verison (from the subversion repositories) so I have full range of tools from the docs.

Here are my models for grins:

```
class Category (models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 128)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Link (models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    fame = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 1)
    url = models.URLField(max_length = 2048)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    active = models.BooleanField(default = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Vote (models.Model):
    link = models.ForeignKey(Link)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    karma_delta = models.SmallIntegerField(default = 1)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.karma_delta)
```

How I am able to turn

```
def latest(request):
    links = Link.objects.all().order_by('-created')[:20]
    return render_to_response('links/list.html', {'links': links})
```

Into the above query?

I've only been able to make some progress using things like [Aggregation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) but how to tackle my use of CASE is beyond me.  Any help would be much appreciated.  I always prefer to work in a framework's built in ORM but if raw SQL is necessary...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have time at the moment to attempt a full translation of that query, but if the CASE is your main stumbling block, I can tell you right now it isn't supported natively, you'll need to use a call to [.extra()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra-select-none-where-none-params-none-tables-none-order-by-none-select-params-none) with some raw SQL for that. Something like:

```
.extra(select={'user_vote': 'SUM(CASE WHEN links_vote.user_id = 1 THEN links_vote.karma_delta ELSE 0 END')})
```

But if this query works well as-is, why bother translating it into the ORM? Just [grab a cursor and run it as a SQL query](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/). Django's ORM is intentionally not a 100% solution, there's a reason it exposes the raw cursor API.

**Update**: And since Django 1.2, there's also [Manager.raw()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#django.db.models.Manager.raw) to let you make raw SQL queries and get model objects back (thanks Van Gale).

Comment: There's also QuerySet.raw() coming in 1.2: http://simonwillison.net/static/2009/djugl-december.html